# Rails: after creating user with Devise, set user's profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After creating an user with devise, i want to  create auto User's profile.

After creating user trying to use User.last.profile on Rails console

```
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
=> nil


class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_one :profile
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :cash, null: false, default: "0"

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at Rails callbacks.

Go through
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object

Solution would be, add this in *user* model

```
after_commit :create_default_profile, on: :create

private

def create_default_profile
  self.create_profile!
  # self.profile.new(pass_default_attrs).save!
end
```